# CakePHP Auth login error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, authentication

I have users, groups, and a users_groups. This is a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. Everything is associated as it should however upon login there is a SQL error because it is trying to find group_id in the users table which doesn't exist.

The association is made through the users_groups table. has anyone ever run into this problem?

It should be joining on users_groups and not looking for a group_id in the users table.

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.group_id' in 'on clause'

SQL Query:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`is_active`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`description`, `Group`.`active`, `Group`.`created`, `Group`.`modified`, `Group`.`parent_id` FROM `seotools`.`sa_users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `seotools`.`sa_groups` AS `Group` ON (`User`.`group_id` = `Group`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`username` = 'mhardy' AND `User`.`password` = 'f30d110154184d05759871e97bfec0a72e8c317a' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HABTM table to "groups_users", to [follow cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).

> This new join table’s name needs to include the names of both models
>   involved, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore ( _
>   ). The contents of the table should be two fields, each foreign keys
>   (which should be integers) pointing to both of the primary keys of the
>   involved models

Or use the overiding options in the User and Group model to keep the table name as "users_groups".

Comment: I apologize... it is groups_users... all of the HABTM tables are in alphabetical order. That was just a flub when I was asking the question. The association is working everywhere. In all actions and views things are as they should be. for some reason on the login action it is trying to use group_id in the User model. I have built the same structure in a new app and it isn't doing it. so I am at a loss as to why it would be in this case.

Comment: Then can you please post your models to check the associations and the code of the controller (or request) that's causing the problem?

Comment: Oh, and if was just a mistype, update your question with the code of the login that's causing the problem and all the information you just told me on the comment, so I can delete this answer since it's not addressing your real problem :)